# Как работает оператор else if и в чем отличие от if?

Tags: любой-язык, условия

Чем отличается оператор `else if` от обычного `if` ?

Цепочка операторов из `if-else if`

```
if (condition)
    statement;
else if (condition)
    statement;
else if (condition)
    statement;
```

Цепочка операторов из if

```
if (condition)
    statement;
if (condition)
    statement;
if (condition)
    statement;
```

Есть ли между ними разница в работе?

Comment: Вы случаем не `return statement;` имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Достаточно рассмотреть простой пример, чтобы понять, в чем заключается разница.

```
int x = 0;

if ( x == 0 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
else if ( x == 1 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
else if ( x == 2 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет

```
x = 0
```

А если этот код переписать в виде

```
if ( x == 0 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
if ( x == 1 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
if ( x == 2 )
{
    System.out.printline( "x = " + x );
    ++x;
}
```

то вывод на консоль будет

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
```

То есть в первом случае предложения  `if` выполняются в зависимости от условий, а во втором случае они выполняются безусловно, то есть не зависит от выполнения предыдущих `if` предложений.

Answer (score 9):

Есть. Формат `if/else if` гарантирует, что при выполнении какого-либо из условий блоки с другими условиями не будут выполнены. При использовании цепочки `if` это не гарантируется. Например:

```
int a = 10;
if( a > 1 )
  System.out.println( "Переменная 'a' больше 1" );
if( a > 5 )
  System.out.println( "Переменная 'a' больше 5" );
```

Будут выполнены оба блока, и выведется:

```
Переменная 'a' больше 1
Переменная 'a' больше 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Как такового оператора `else if` нет, это лишь использование ещё одного `if` в ветке `else` другого `if`. 
Но разница между ними есть. В первом случае второе условие отработает, если не отработает первое, а третье - если не отработает второе. Во втором случае отработают все условия (если где-то не возникнет, скажем, исключение).

НО. Судя по вашему коду, условия у вас одинаковые. Поэтому в первом случае сработает тоьлко первый `if` или не сработает ничего. А во втором либо сработают все три `if`, либо не сработает ничего

Comment: В рамках тэга «любой язык» высказывание `как такового оператора ... нет` не совсем верно, ибо есть языки, которые выделяют на сей случай отдельной оператор в духе `elseif`

Answer (score 1):

В if вы даёте условие и если оно не выполняется можете вызвать else . Но в случаях когда нужно проверять условие одно за одним можно использовать  конструкцию else if . И тогда в else if вы вписание ещё одно условие .

```
       int x = 1;
    if(x==3){
        System.out.println("Это число 5");//к сожелению не выведет
    }else if(x==2){
        System.out.println("Это число 2");//к сожелению не выведет
    }else if(x==1){
        System.out.println("Это число 1");//выведет вот это
    }else {
        System.out.println("Число вообще не ходит");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во втором случае у вас проверяются всегда все условия. В первом случае если выполнится первое условие остальные уже не проверяются

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, конструкция

```
if (condition)
    statement;
else if (condition)
    statement;
else if (condition)
    statement;
```

чаще всего применяется, когда нужно в зависимости от того, чему равно проверяемое значение, выполнить несколько вариантов действий. И вообще по-идее в таких ситуациях нужно пользоваться оператором ветвления (`switch\case\select` и т.д). Но во многих языках он обладает неприятными ограничениями, которые заставляют пользоваться вышеупомянутой конструкцией.
Зачем вставлять `else`, если логика последующих `if` такова, что проверку пройдёт только один? Чтобы избежать лишних проверок и явно указать читателю исходного кода, что здесь реализован по сути оператор ветвления.

---

В некоторых языках реализован специальный оператор `elseif\elsif\elif` позволяющий избегать лишнего вложения блоков.

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно воспользоватся оператором множественного выбора `switch()`.

```
int value;
cin >> value;

switch(value){
    case 1: return value+1;
    case 2: return value+2;
    default: return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут при **выполнения первого условия**, к второму условию **не дойдёт**. Если первого не отвечает условия, а второе да - прекратятся все проверки, до 3-го не дойдёт

```
if (condition)
    statement;
else if (condition)
    statement;
```

Тут выполнятся **все условия**, независимо сработает ли первое, ты по сути дублируешь проверку "если"

```
if (condition)
    statement;
if (condition)
    statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно понимать перевод данных значений:

if - если

else if - иначе если

Пример есть в песне советской "Если у вас нету тёти":

if у вас нету тёти - хорошо

else if вам её потерять - плохо

Comment: Ну ок, "если нету тёти", а почему "иначе если вам её потерять"? И почему одно хорошо, а второе плохо? Какой-то странный пример

Answer (score -1):

Да, в `else-if` варианте переход к следующей ветке происходит только тогда, когда предыдущая дала результат `false`.

```
int a = 1
int b = 2
int c = 3

if (a == 1)
    statement;
else if (b == 2)
    statement; // эта ветка не будет выполнена
else if (c == 3)
    statement; // эта ветка не будет выполнена
```

Если Вы уберете все `else-if`, все три ветки будут выполнены. Поэтому `else-if` используется как последовательность, которая должны быть проверена, если предыдущая дала неверный результат.